# How to convert Gregorian string to Gregorian Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar, java-ee-7, gregorian-calendar

I have to compute something based on the Calendar's date, but I am receiving the complete Gregorian Calendar's String value.

Eg i/p received `{may be - "new GregorianCalendar().toString()"} as String :- java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1410521241348,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=37,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=12,DAY_OF_YEAR=255,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=12,MINUTE=27,SECOND=21,MILLISECOND=348,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000]`

I want to extract the Calendar's date value to process further computation.

Comment: You can't in this way. You can take `String` as `Json` `String`.

Comment: @DeiAndrei `GregorianCalendar` Object is not Simple one and also Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toString%28%29

Comment: I missread the question, my apologies.

Comment: Good luck!  That's not a standard format, close as I can tell, but simply a toString dump or some such.  You're gonna have to write ad-hoc code to parse it.  (It might help to say a Gregorian chant while you work.)

Comment: Isnt there an easy solution for this by just converting or parsing?

Comment: Yep, simple matter of programming.

Comment: As I told you, maybe someone will come along and tell you what regex to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are too complicated or wrong. The following will give you the *milliseconds since the epoch*, which is a universal timestamp that you can easily convert to most time representation classes, including `Calendar` or `Date`:

```
Pattern gregorianPattern = Pattern.compile("^java.util.GregorianCalendar\\[time=(\\d+).*"); 

Matcher matcher = gregorianPattern.matcher(param);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    return Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!!  A very concise solution. This is what I was looking for 1-year ago :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could find the time in the input string and convert it to a Gregorian Calendar. Then you would have to set its timezone as specified in the ZoneInfo field. Something like this might work:

```
    String calendarAsString="java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1410521241348,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"Europe/London\",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=37,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=12,DAY_OF_YEAR=255,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=12,MINUTE=27,SECOND=21,MILLISECOND=348,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000]";

    int timeStart=calendarAsString.indexOf("time=")+5;
    int timeEnd=calendarAsString.indexOf(',');
    String timeStr=calendarAsString.substring(timeStart, timeEnd);
    long timeInMillis=Long.parseLong(timeStr);

    int timezoneIdStart=calendarAsString.indexOf("\"")+1;
    int timezoneIdEnd=calendarAsString.indexOf("\",");
    String timeZoneStr=calendarAsString.substring(timezoneIdStart, timezoneIdEnd);

    System.out.println("time="+timeInMillis+" zone="+timeZoneStr);
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneStr));
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);

    System.out.println(calendarAsString);
    System.out.println(calendar);
```

or you can use a regular expression to do it, instead

```
    String regex="time=([0-9]*),.*ZoneInfo\\[id=\"([^\"]*)\"";
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(calendarAsString);
    matcher.find();
    timeStr=matcher.group(1);
    timeInMillis=Long.parseLong(timeStr);
    timeZoneStr=matcher.group(2);
    System.out.println("time="+timeInMillis+" zone="+timeZoneStr);
    calendar=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneStr));
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
    System.out.println(calendar);
```

Note: if you just want the calendar's Date value, you can construct it from the timeInMillis, without having to reconstruct the whole GregorianCalendar object (and without having to find the timezone if you don't want to).

```
    Date date=new Date(timeInMillis);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
GregorianCalendar g=new GregorianCalendar(1975, 5, 7);
    Date d=g.getTime();
    System.out.println(g.toString());
    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd"); 
    System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

This is way to grab date from GregorianCalendar. i wish this will help to you

Adding more to this, you can retrieve any information you want using the format. It's just a matter of providing the correct format.

Ex:
Adding z or Z provides you with the timezone information

```
"yyyy MM dd z" - 2014 10 12 PDT
"yyyy MM dd Z" - 2014 10 12 -0700
```

Adding a 'T' would result in something like this:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ" - 2014-10-12T14:23:51.890+0530
```

In this HH represents hours in 24 hour format mm minutes ss seconds sss milliseconds.

Comment: does this answer original question?

Comment: This does not explain how to retrieve the date from the original input string described in the question